# Handling the click on the UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In a `UITableViewCell` of the second section of my `UITableView`, i have defined a `UISegmentedControl` composed of two buttons:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    allerRetour = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Y aller", nil),                                  NSLocalizedString(@"En partir", nil), nil]];
    [allerRetour setFrame:CGRectMake(9.0f, 0.0f, 302.0f, 45.0f)];
    allerRetour.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [cell addSubview:allerRetour];
}

return cell;
```

Now, when i click on a button of that two buttons in the segmented control, i want to track that, so i try this in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but it doesn't work (The NSLog is not displaying, so the event isn't thrown):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==0)
    {   
        if (allerRetour.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            labelModeRecherche.text=@"Départ"; 
            NSLog(@"Départ");
        }
        else
        {
            labelModeRecherche.text=@"Arrivée";   
            NSLog(@"Arrivée");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking on the actual segmented control will not cause a didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Instead, you need to add a target, like so:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And define the "action:" method to respond to the event.

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
```

Then put the code of the inside if in that action method.

Comment: I have already did that, i had a look at UISegmentedControl in the documentation for that, however, nothing is changed, but your approach is suitable in many other cases, probably not mine :)

Comment: What do you mean it's not suitable? Are you trying to get this to work on multiple rows? I may be able to help (in french if needed :))